# Produce a power symbol ^ without Overleaf forcing math mode

Tags: math-mode

I am writing MATLAB code into LaTex for a report and I would like to show the power symbol (^). However when I use h=2*(0.6.^i).*u; it raises i to a superscript and gives the message "I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed." Is there anyway it can still compile without math mode?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If I correctly understood your question, than `h=2*(0.6.\^{}i).*u` should give what you looking for.

Comment: That should work, it looks smaller than normal, but should work, thank you!

Comment: You can consider using `\mathtt{h=2*(0.6.\^{}i).*u}`

Comment: `\verb|h=2*(0.6.^i).*u;|`?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for `verbatim` format in `text`, as you are not providing any `MWE`, I assume that you are using standard template, and the codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\verb!h=2*(0.6.^i).*u!
\end{document}
```

PS: This was already suggested by `Henri` as in `comment`